# Flex printing on OSX pushes image off the page. How can this be fixed?

Tags: apache-flex, printing

My Flex 3 app prints pages just fine from browsers on Windows using FlexPrintJob (not the browser print function). However, on OSX, the left and top margins show up larger and the page gets pushed off the right and bottom. Basically, the scaling is screwed up, and I can't see any way to adjust the margins in code.

Has anyone seen this discrepancy in Flex printing between Windows and OSX? Are there any known workarounds? I've searched all over and I can't find any good info on this (other than 12 unresolved printing bugs in the Adobe Jira DB).

And please don't say "don't print in Flex". I know Flex sucks at printing, but I have to use it. Thanks!

**Edit:**

PDF Generation is one route and while its a valid solution for some folks, I need to print directly. I'd like to see stuff like using regular Flash PrintJob, monkeypatches to FlexPrintJob, or just ways I can format my DisplayObjects before sending them to FlexPrintJob. None of the scaling options in FlexPrintJob work. My Flex Component is at 1.0 scale. I'm not sure what else I can do except for mess around with regular PrintJob. I'm putting a bounty on this for answers in this domain.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to PDF generation. There are two ways to do this without having to purchase server-side licenses:

1. Use our library of Flex components - clear.swc, a part of open source Clear Toolkit available on Sourceforge. This process is described in Ch. 11 of the book Enterprise Development with Flex currently available as rough cuts on safaribooksonline.com
2. Use open-source library alivePDF.

Don't print by Flex PrintJob :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yakov. See my edit above... I will generate PDFs in the future, but I need to print directly now.

Comment: good luck i spent a full week trying to get a 2 page report printing in actionscript. it is nigh impossible to print if it's not all fixed height